# Hacer diferentes clicks en un ngFor

Tags: angular

Tengo un ngFor en el cual saco 5 elementos, quiero que al hacer click cambie el color de ese elemento solo, pero no de los demás. Como podría hacerlo?

```
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let fpermisos of permisos | slice:0:5; let i = index">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle" [ngClass]="{'ver-activado': ver, 'ver-desactivado': !ver}" (click)=Updatever();></i>
      <i class="fas fa-eye" [ngClass]="{'habilitar-activado': habilitar, 'habilitar-desactivado': !habilitar}" (click)=Updatehabilitar();></i> {{fpermisos.titulo}}</li>
   </ul>
```

Mi componente:

```
  Updatever() {
    if(this.ver == false) {
      this.ver = true;
    } else {
      this.ver = false;
    }
  }

  Updatehabilitar() {
    if(this.habilitar == false) {
      this.habilitar = true;
    } else {
      this.habilitar = false;
    }
  }
```

Por más vueltas que le doy no consigo hacerlo Y.Y

Comment: "ver" deberia ser un array con 5 elementos, de tal manera que cuando cambies el estado de una de los elementos hagas this.ver[i] = true/false, donde i es el número de elemento a cambiar. La clase de los elementos i dependerá también de ver[i]

Comment: Si yo hago un console.log(this.permisos[0]); me muestra el primer permiso, y así sucesivamente pero no se como implementarlo

Answer (score 1):

Añade al objeto de los permisos dos atributos: ver y habilitado en los cuales esten en false y las funciones del click que cambien ese valor, ese valor es el que determina el css:

TS

```
permisos = [
  {
    titulo: "l1",
    visto: false,
    habilitado: false
  },
  {
    titulo: "l2",
    visto: false,
    habilitado: false
  },
  {
    titulo: "l3",
    visto: false,
    habilitado: false
  },
  {
    titulo: "l4",
    visto: false,
    habilitado: false
  }
];

Updatever(permiso) {
  console.log(permiso)
permiso.visto = !permiso.visto
}

Updatehabilitar(permiso) {
  console.log(permiso)
  permiso.habilitado = !permiso.habilitado
}
```

HTML

```
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let fpermisos of permisos | slice:0:5; let i = index">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle" [ngClass]="{'visto': fpermisos.visto}" (click)="Updatever(fpermisos)"></i> 
      <i class="fas fa-eye" [ngClass]="{'habiltado': fpermisos.habilitado}" (click)="Updatehabilitar(fpermisos)"> </i> {{fpermisos.titulo}}</li>
   </ul>
```

CSS

```
  .visto {
    color: green
  }
  .habiltado {
    color: green
  }
```